# how this component passes props, as it is neither parent component nor child component to access them? also it passes them without any curly braces?

Tags: reactjs

## App.js

```
import { getImageUrl } from './utils.js';

function Avatar({ person, size }) {
  return (
    <img
      className="avatar"
      src={getImageUrl(person)}
      alt={person.name}
      width={size}
      height={size}
    />
  );
}

export default function Profile() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Avatar
        size={100}
        person={{ 
          name: 'Katsuko Saruhashi', 
          imageId: 'YfeOqp2'
        }}
      />
  </div>
  );
}
```

## utility.js

```
export function getImageUrl(person, size = 's')   // --> talking about this line
     {
     return (
     'https://i.imgur.com/' +
     person.imageId +
     size +
     '.jpg'
      );
      }
```

This component is an utility function that exports image url, person and size are the props that has been passed from parent to child component, this function is imported in the child component so is it possible that " A component which is neither parent nor child component can access the props ".
is there any way to declare them ?
how it can pass those arguments

Comment: `getImageUrl` is not a component, it's a function. The data is passed through an argument

Comment: as it is passed as a function, this is the only reason why we are assigning src to getImageUrl in { }, do we consider this function as javascript code not a component? please verify it if i am wrong?  how do we use getImageUrl as a component in app.js